# Transpose Data from columns to rows

Tags: sql-server, r, excel

I am planning to work on "High-Utility Item set mining" via java based SPMF tool. But the issue is getting the data into right format before load the data into SPMF.

My current format:

```
 Transaction #  Item    Amount

        1001    200 14
        1001    201 13
        1001    202 16
        1001    205 17
        1002    300 11
        1002    305 12
        1002    200 30
```

Desired output: (No transaction number needed, each transaction is one line)

```
200 201 202 205:60:14 13 16 17
300 305 200:53:11 12 30
```

Explanation for desired output:

```
200 201 202 205 --->   are Items (left of 1st row)
14 13 16 17      --->  are Amount (right of first row)
:60:          ---->    is total amount of transaction # 1001 (14+13+16+17)
```

I am open to any solution. I can load my current format into SQL and extract the data via SQL query if I get right query to achieve my output.
Please help.

Answer (score 4):

Using `by` for example :

```
by(dx,dx$Transaction,function(x)c(x$Item,sum(x$Amount),x$Amount))

dx$Transaction: 1001
[1] 200 201 202 205  60  14  13  16  17
------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
dx$Transaction: 1002
[1] 300 305 200  53  11  12  30
```

> 

Comment: Wonderful solution. Thank you so much. One quick request. I am not an expert in R but that is ok. One request…is it possible to add “:” for ‘Total amount’ right and left side?
And also can I get rid of headings of “dx$Transaction: 1001”. I have to process this code for few million lines. 

Desired output is..
200 201 202 205:60:14 13 16 17
300 305 200:53:11 12 30